# Is cuda suitable for array filtering

Tags: cuda

I am working on optimizing a program with a time complexity of O(N^7). I have an array of strings, represented as 32 bit integers, where each bit corresponds to a specific character in the input string. The job is to find all combinations of input strings, where each character is present exactly once, and having all characters present. The naive solutions require 7 layers of recursion, with each layer iterating over the entire list. This pretty soon becomes extremely slow.

So I was wondering if I could use cuda to speed up the process a bit, by feeding the GPU with an array of possible strings, and a bitmask that should not be matched, and get a filtered list back, so I could speed up the recursive steps a bit.

So the question is: Is this kind of filtering suitable for parallel processing?

What I am doing in C right now is described below.

```
void recursive_search (unsigned int used, unsigned int *list, int listlen,
                       int start,unsigned int * stack, int reclevel) {
  int index, newindex;
  newindex = 0;

  for (index=0; index< listlen; index++) {
    if (!list[index] & used) {
      newlist[newindex++] = list[index];
    }
  }      

  if ((newindex == 1 && (used | newlist[0])) == 0xffffffff) {
    /* Hooray! We have a match */
    stack[reclevel] = newlist[0];
    report_match(stack);
    return;
  }

  for (index = 0;index < newindex; index++) {
    recursive_search (used | newlist[index], newlist, newindex,
                      index, stack, reclevel + 1);
  }
}
```

I hope this make my question clearer.

Comment: The problem description is not very clear, at least it is not clear to me. O(7)? That is the same as O(1), i.e. constant time. I would assume that time complexity is at the very least O(n), i.e. linear, where n is the total number of characters across all the strings, but your comment that that the process becomes extremeny slow would suggest exponential growth. Can you show the actual code, or at least pseudo-code of your algorithm?

Comment: Sorry, O(N^7). Yes, I can provide some pseuedo code. It's too late for me to be really clear now, so sometime tomorrow.

Comment: As I understand your problem description so far, you are just looking for [all possible permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations) of the characters of your alphabet?

Comment: No, I'm looking for all permutations of my list of input strings, that end up with having each character of my input alphabet represented exactly once.

Comment: First, convert your algorithm into a recursion-free form. Then think about parallelizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not try to convert the full algorithm into a single kernel. Try to parallelize each step one by one.

This code section below may be converted to a copy_if statement.

```
for (index=0; index< listlen; index++) {
    if (!list[index] & used) {
        newlist[newindex++] = list[index];
    }
}
```

And the statement is like

```
thrust::copy_if(list.begin(), list.end(), newlist.begin(), predicate());
```

So you will achieve your new list easily.

You can generate the array of possible strings on the GPU?

About the recursion:

- Because you will have many, many threads active in the GPU, there might be more than one result/match possible. Returning first match, or all matches may be a problem.
- If recursion is a must, you may call the kernel several times by storing the partial progress in the global memory at each time.
- As @harrism indicated, you may convert the recursive part to a simpler flow and let the parallelism handle each cases.

Comment: The list filtering step is what takes up most of the execution time, so even if that's the only part possible, that alone would be a good enough performance boost, that it is worth the effort.

I'm well aware that recursion isn't suited for parallelism, and that the flow would have to be different. But as I have no prior experience in this area, my question was meant to find out if it at all was possible. The C code was just to explain the problem.

And thank you for the answer.